# Visual studio Express Edition vs Community

Tags: visual-studio

My question is What is difference between **Visual Studio Express Edition for Desktop** and
**Visual Studio Community** version?

I want use VS to create Desktop apps, currently I have ultimate version of VS2013, but I think mentioned versions are lighter and faster and **FULL FREE** for me because I don't use most of developing features like *Team server or Testing tools or IntelliTrace, ...*. I want know the mentioned versions have full Windows API Support (Header files definition) like Ultimate/Enterprise versions?

Don't forget my first question: VS Express for Desktop *vs* Community, because both are FREE.

Comment: I think all versions of visual studio have full support of Windows API. It's actually provided by the OS DLLs (kernel32, user32 and etc.). Probably some may not contain the newest version of MFC with fancy ribbons and etc., but who cares?

Comment: YES, of course, But header files should exist and supported by MFC.

Answer (score 35):

Community edition is the full fledged software, but you can't use it on enterprise (>5 users)

On the other hand, Express editions can be used in enterprise environments, but does not let you use plugins.

So in the end, as far as I can tell the choice is between plugins and enterprise. If it's just a product you are developing yourself, or an open source software, Community edition would be your best bet. On the other hand, if you want to try out the latest version at your work for free, then Express edition is for you.

Comment: No one seems to mention the significance of plugins, so that one can determine if will need it. But your mention of 'plugins' vs. enterprise is probably the most important difference.

Comment: [Unless you are working on an approved open-source project - no limit on users doing that!](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt553321/). Thank you for reading the fine print for me!

Answer (score 23):

Here is from the "source" :)

[Differences between Visual Studio Community Edition and Express Editions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onecode/archive/2014/11/12/differences-between-visual-studio-community-edition-and-express-editions.aspx)

Here is a quote from that MSDN blog:

> There are two main differences between Visual Studio Community Edition
>   and the Express Editions
>
> 1) Visual Studio Express Editions do not allow users to use extensions
>   (aka. plugins).  There are over 5000 great plugins for Visual Studio
>   in Visual Studio Gallery.  Plugins such as Developer Assistant can
>   boost developers’ productivity.  Unfortunately, they are not available
>   to Visual Studio Express users.   With Visual Studio Community
>   Edition, you can access and use All of them!
>
> 2) Visual Studio Express Editions are targeting specific platforms: 
>   Express for Web allows you to develop Web apps;  Express for Windows
>   allows you to develop Windows apps; Express for Windows Desktop allows
>   you to develop desktop apps.  But with Visual Studio Community
>   Edition, you can develop projects targeting cross-platforms.

Answer (score 8):

Community is like a full version of Visual Studio Professional, only they don't allow you to develop for commercial purposes (through the licence agreement). With the exception for developing apps that you sell in the Windows Store.

Why you would want Community (dito for VS Professional):

1. You can develop a mix of different projects in the same solution on the same IDE. With Express you develop asp.net and other web apps (Express for Web) in different IDE's than you would developing a Windows Forms applicaiton (Express for Win Forms).
2. You get full access to plugins that enhance the IDE, like code optimisation tools.
3. Other than Professional, Community is integrated with a lot of online collaboration sites. Like integration to GIT repos and Windows Azure hosting.

Express is like the old school express versions, if you used to use the old school express versions, you probably want to stick to it. It allows for commercial development, but they restrict the features of the IDE. And they make it harder to use by splitting the IDE to only handle Web Applications (like ASP.Net) in one IDE and a different IDE for handling Windows Forms. (In the past they also split the Win Forms IDEs to only handle one coding language like C# or VB).

Comment: really, splitting for Web, Windows, or Windows Desktop - in Express is not convinient... & besides in 2019 there is no more Express edition, as I know. But writting commercial code only (for Windows Store) - in Community - also not always suitable for business purposes... vs_build_tools left useful yet... (am not sure about 32x development)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/) is the official comparison

I think `IntelliTrace` is the most important part missing in the community edition. Cloning the repo some similar things are missing. but I don't think those are any real problems.

Comment: The linked page doesn't list Express. I'm guessing they changed it.